# How to connect to a shared mailbox?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am able to connect to my mailbox perfectly fine using the following code

```
  Store store = session.getStore("imap");
  store.connect(host, user, password);
```

But whenever I try to connect to a shared mailbox, it throws a `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed` error

```
 store.connect(host, "domainxxx.com" + "\\" + user + "\\" + "shared_mailbox_alias", password);
```

I read an article that `domain\user\alias` format is only supported for the 2010 version of exchange. **How else can i connect ?**

*I use this shared mailbox in my outlook everyday, and it works fine, so I know its running well.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the JavaMail wiki we have this [note about Exchange](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Exchange):

> To access a shared mailbox in Exchange, you need to login using the "alias" name and password for the shared mailbox, which you can get from your Exchange server administrator. [This article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/bg-BG/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/8c8b4605-efae-49eb-a118-54aa418de6c2) has more information.

Note that Outlook uses a Microsoft-proprietary protocol, which works differently than IMAP.  Not all features of Exchange are accessible through IMAP.